# In bash, show a list with: process cpu time, nice priority and custom command. in different columns

Tags: bash, unix

The custom comand is: the calculation of the relation between resident memory and the need of exchange memory necessary to store the process in case of suspending it and the owner of the process.
I know `ps -eo cputime,nice` but I want another column with my custom calculation  and I dont know how.

P.D. And if I want to add in my script: `-nice a b`, where it will process only the processes in "a-b" range how it could be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -eo cputime,nice | awk '{print $1,$2,"your_custom_column"}'
```

Where in place `your_custom_column` you can put what ever you want

Comment: `ps -eo cputime,nice | awk '{print $1,$2,"your_custom_column"}' `
With that I only achieve show a constant value in that custom column, but I try to show the result of a command in the column for example:
`ps -eo cputime,nice | awk '{print $1,$2,"echo $((2+4))'`

with your example with that show in my console: `00:00:00 0 echo $((2+4))`

And I want `00:00:00 0 6`